# Обобщенные алгоритмы в c# - что такое?

Tags: c#, алгоритм, generics, полиморфизм, делегаты

Что такое обобщенные алгоритмы? В чем состоит их цель и задача?

Я понял, что обобщенный алгоритм – это алгоритм, результат которого зависит от места, из которого он вызывается. И данные алгоритмы могут быть написаны(реализованы) с помощью  обобщенных типов, полиморфизма или делегатов.

Но я так и не смог найти достойного объяснения и описания этих алгоритмов, и найти понятных примеров.

Не могли бы вы поподробнее рассказать о них, показать примеры этих алгоритмов с обобщенными типами, полиморфизмом и делегатами, и показать в чем заключается общность этих трех подходов?

Comment: Ваш вопрос участвует в конкурсе: [Новогодний алгоритм 2016](http://meta.ru.stackoverflow.com/q/2235)

Answer (score 1):

**Обобщённый алгоритм** - это такой алгоритм, который можно применять к различным типам данных не меняя его самого (то есть, его реализацию). Реализуются они на основе обобщённых типов (generics).

Это, если в двух словах. Более подробное описание парадигмы обобщённого программирования можно посмотреть, например, [здесь](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B8.D0.BC.D0.B5.D1.80_.D0.BD.D0.B0_C.23) и [здесь](http://www.argc-argv.com/2_2005/article01.pdf).

Answer (score 1):

В c# алгоритмы определяются в виде методов. Если метод должен работать с разными типами, то метод можно определить как обобщенный.
Пример обобщенного метода, который создает объекты разных типов и выводит название типа в консоль.

```
T Get<T>() where T : new() {
   Console.WriteLine("creating type: " + typeof(T).FullName);
   return new T(); 
}
```

`T` -- это обозначение любого типа. вместо `T` можно указать, например, `SomeClass`.
`where T : new()`  -- ограничение: у типа должен быть конструктор.

Пример использования обобщенного метода `Get<T>`

```
class C { public C() {} }

var c = Get<C>();
```

Также обобщенные методы позволяют избежать boxing и unboxing.
Например, надо получить информацию об объекте. 
Если не использовать обобщения, то пишем так

```
string Info(object o) { ... }
```

При вызове метода для value-типов, например, `Info(1)` происходит boxing 1.
Чтобы его избежать надо определить метод как обобщенный.

```
string Info<T>(T o) { ... }
```