# Можно ли проверить наличие у типа реализованных операторов сравнения?

Tags: c#

**Дано:** Обобщенный метод использующий сравнения элементов в своей работе.
**Необходимо:** обеспечить контроль на этапе компиляции, что в качестве параметра типа, передан тип реализующий операторы сравнения.

Очевидный вариант сделать так:

```
void SomeMethod<T>(T a, T b) where T:IComparable<T>
{
    if (a.CompareTo(b)>0) //Some action
    ...
}
```

Но такое определение гарантирует только наличие метода `a.CompareTo(b)`. Это нормально при работе со ссылочными типами, но при работе с value-типами, например `int`, при вызове метода, вызывает боксинг значений. Хотелось бы этого избежать, если возможно конечно.

Comment: var t = typeof(T) или var t = o.GetType(); foreach(var m in t.GetMembers()) { ... }

Comment: @Stack это я знаю, хотелось без привлечения рефлесии, но похоже вариантов нет.

Comment: _"при работе с value-типами, например int, при вызове метода, вызывает боксинг значений."_ -- обобщенные методы позволяют избежать boxing/unboxing. см. [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/480122/196972)

Comment: @Stack спасибо, уже проверил в LINQPad-е, там можно посмотреть IL-код отдельного выражения. Сейчас поправлю это в вопросе, чтобы не сбивало других с толку.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вас интересует возможность задать ограничение дженерика по наличию перегруженных операторов сравнения, то, боюсь, это невозможно.

С другой стороны в приведенном вами варианте с использованием интерфейса `IComparable<T>` упаковки не происходит, поскольку вы используете обобщённый интерфейс, метод `CompareTo` которого принимает строго определённый тип, а не object. Можете проверить это, изучив сгенерированный il-код - инструкция box там не используется.

Comment: в IL коде самого дженерика боксинга нет даже если использовать не обобщенный IComparable. Просто стоит ссылка на вызов метода. Это и смущает. Но по идее вы правы, если на стороне класса все реализовано правильно, проблемы быть не должно.