# Сравнение типов значений

Tags: c#

Есть метод:

```
int[] Sort(int[] Array) {
   // алгоритм сортировки 
}
```

Он работает только с массивами типа `int`.
Как сделать так, чтобы он мог работать с любыми типами значений, ведь алгоритм один и тот же?
Я думал, что если работать с массивом типа `ValueType`, но к нему нельзя применять операторы сравнения. 
Как быть?

Comment: Пробовали через generic? T Sort(T Array); а для ValueType переопределить операторы сравнения

Comment: Да, похоже что generic - то, что нужно. Спасибо

Comment: @user2455111 оформите как ответ?

Comment: @Ev_Hyper оформил )

Comment: _Я думал, что если работать с массивом типа ValueType, но к нему нельзя применять операторы сравнения._ - массив это ссылочный тип а не ValueType. К чему конкретно и как нельзя применять операторы сравнения?

Comment: тут есть вариант обобщенного метода, который использует сравнение, но не использует операторы сравнения и гарантирует, что значения можно сравнивать, не обязательно ValueType http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487814/198316

Answer (score 2):

Используйте интерфейс `IComparable<T>`  [тык](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
  {
     var arr = new IComparable[] {1,2,3};
     var sorted = Sort(arr, arr.Length);         
  }

  private static IComparable[] Sort(IComparable[] arr, int arrLength)
  {
     for (int i = 0; i < arrLength; i++)
     {
       var t =  arr[i].CompareTo(3);
     }
     return arr;
  }
```

Comment: *“Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.”*

Comment: вот только для сортировки нужны операторы < >, а на T нельзя навесить ограничение "реализует <" или "реализует >"

Comment: @PashaPash, тут VladD говорит что скоро будет можно :) И вроде можно поставить constraint - IComparable или как-то так?

Comment: @Grundy можно, но про это стоило бы упомянуть в ответе :)

Comment: @PashaPash, ответ не мой, я только комментарий разместил :)

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за замечания, поправил ответ их учетом

Comment: после исправления generic не нужен, ты нигде не используешь тип `T`

Comment: нужно спешить, поправлю позже