# C#. Можно ли перегрузить операторы сравнения в обобщенных классах?

Tags: c#, классы, generics

Есть следующий обобщенный класс (он пока не реализован до конца):

```
class QuickSorter<Type>
{
    private void Swap(ref Type a, ref Type b)
    {
        Type temp = a;
        a = b;
        b = temp;
    }
    public void Sort(Type[] Array)
    {
        //Sort_Recursion(Array);
    }

    private void Sort_Recursion(Type[] Array, int L, int R)
    { 
        /*
        Type Median = Array[L + (R - L)/2]; // (L + R)/2 = L/2 + R/2 = L - L/2 + R/2 = L + (R - L)/2 ==> Для избежания переполнения

        int l = L;
        int r = R; 

        while (l <= r)
        {
            while (Array[l] < Median)

        }
        */    
    }

    public static bool operator >(Type a, Type b)
    {

    }

    public static bool operator <(Type a, Type b)
    {

    }

}
```

Идея следующая: 
я хочу реализовать алгоритм быстрой сортировки для заданных типов данных (для целочисленных, вещественных, символьных). Хотел бы сделать это в одном классе. Подумал воспользоваться обобщенным классом, но в процессе написания кода столкнулся с проблемой сравнения переменных обобщенного типа. Перегрузка операторов для типа `Type` невозможна в классе `QuickSorter`. Есть ли способ реализовать перегрузку операторов сравнения для типа `Type` в обобщенном классе? Может быть, есть другое подходящее решение для данной задачи?

Comment: скорее всего лучше задать ограничение на тип-параметр для генерика каким-нибудь [`IComparable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.icomparable(v=vs.110).aspx) или [`IComparable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/4d7sx9hd(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Согласен с @Grundy. Перегрузка операторов - это история из C++, да и муторно это. Проще реализовать в/у интерфейсы.

Comment: посмотрите тут http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/487814/198316, в вопросе как раз есть вариант как использовать сравнение без операторов

Comment: @Grundy как показал личный опыт - это единственный адекватный вариант

Comment: Вместо `Type` выберите другое это, например `T`. Такой класс (Type) уже есть в C#

Answer (score 5, accepted):

В языке C# у свойств, индексаторов, событий, **операторных методов**, конструкторов и деструкторов **не может быть параметров-типов**. Однако их можно определить в обобщенном типе с тем, чтобы в их коде использовать параметры-типы этого типа. C# не поддерживает задание собственных обобщенных параметров типа у этих членов, поскольку создатели языка С# из компании Microsoft считают, что разработчикам вряд ли потребуется задействовать эти члены в качестве обобщенных. К тому же для поддержки обобщенного использования этих членов в С# пришлось бы разработать специальный синтаксис, что довольно затратно. Например, при использовании в коде оператора `+` компилятор может вызвать перегруженный операторный метод. Невозможно указать в коде, где есть оператор `+`, какие бы то ни было аргументы типа.

---

**Примечание:** В рекомендациях Microsoft для проектировщиков указано, что переменные параметров должны называться `T` или, в крайнем случае, начинаться с `T` (как, например, `TKey` или `TValue`). `T` означает тип (type), а `I` означает интерфейс (например, `IComparable`)

---

Как правильно заметил @Qwertiy:

> Накладывать ограничения на статические члены C# не позволяет

А операторы сравнения должны быть статическими. Для решения проблемы можно наложить ограничение на класс, например  `class QuickSorter<T> where T : IComparable<T>`, что ограничит использование классом только тех типов, в которых определен интерфейс `IComparable<T>`

Все примитивные типы, кроме `Object`, `Boolean`, реализуют интерфейс `IComparable` и `IComparable<T>`. Тип `Boolean` - реализует только `IComparable`.

**Что это дает?** В операторах сравнения, вы вызываете метод `CompareTo` на сравниваемых экземплярах. Для примитивных типов все будет будет работать, для своих типов придется реализовать этот интерфейс.

---

Хотелось бы еще добавить: не используйте имя `Type` как имя обобщенного типа, поскольку этот тип определен в сборке `mscorlib.dll`, пространство имен `System`. В будущем может возникнуть недопонимание.

Comment: Спасибо за четкое разъяснение! Имя `Type` я использовал по привычке того, что рекомендуется давать названия типам и переменным осмысленные. Но теперь я понял, почему msdn рекомендует прописывать `T` вместо `Type`.

Answer (score 6):

> ```
> class QuickSorter<Type>
> ```

```
class QuickSorter<Type> where Type : IComparable<Type>
```

Теперь ты сможешь на объектах вызывать `CompareTo`, который их и сравнивает.

А накладывать ограничения на статические члены C# не позволяет.

Comment: Спасибо! Оказывается, все так просто.
А если я захочу добавить для класса `QuickSorter<T>` реализуемый интерфейс `ISorter`, то куда его нужно записать в строке `class QuickSorter<T> where T : IComparable<T>`?

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, через запятую?