# C# ошибка. Оператор > невозможно применить к операнду типа T и T

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Реализую свою коллекция наследуясь от интерфейса IList<Т>. Проблемы возникли с методом sort(хотела сделать пузырьковую сортировку)

```
public void BubbleSort() 
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 1; j < Count-1; j++)
            {
                if (_list[j] > _list[j - 1]) // здесь выдает ошибку
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> Ошибка: Оператор > невозможно применить к операнду типа T и T

В интернете посмотрела про это и нашла лишь **CompareTo**, но я не понимаю как с ним работать и что именно он делает.

Как мне все же сравнить элементы списка?

Comment: Мне кажется, что подобное надо делать методами расширения, а не пилить свою коллекцию с "фишками". А по поводу ошибки, ок, а что будет сравнивать ваш метод, если в коллекции допустим будут `bool`? Что должно дать `true > false`? Ведь `T` - это обобщение, которое говорит "любой доступный тип".

Comment: `List<int> list = ...; list.Sort();`

Comment: @aepot автору пузырьком нужно. А там самая медленная сортировка O (n^2) вставками вроде.

Comment: @АртёмОконечников пузырёк тоже не отличается скоростью. :)

Comment: Возможный дубликат: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/621435/212981

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для произвольных типов операторы сравнения (`> , < ...`) неопределены, зато эти типы могут реализовывать интерфейс `IComparable`. Соответственно все сравнения через операторы вам нужно заменить на метод `CompareTo` и поставить [ограничение](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/where-generic-type-constraint) на тип `T`вида `where T : IComparable<T>`. `CompareTo` сравнивает один объект с другим и возвращает `int`, обычно `< 0` означает что объект на котором вызывается метод меньше аргумента, `> 0` - наоборот и `== 0` - равны. Ну и да, все численные типы реализуют этот интерфейс, так что вам ничего реализовывать не надо.

Comment: То есть это будет так выглядеть? `public class MyCollection<T> where T: IList<T>, IComparable<T>` , а в метод добавить  `if (_list[j].CompareTo(_list[j - 1]) < 0) `

Comment: исправила на `public class MyCollection<T> : IList<T> where T: IComparable<T>` и все работает

Answer (score 4):

Обобщения в C# работают в типобезопасном режиме. Это значит, что операции определенные для типа `T` должны быть определены для всех типов удовлетворяющих этому типу `T`. По-умолчанию для типа `T` доступны только операции, определенные для `Object`, так как все типы явно и неявно (через боксинг) наследуются от `Object` и мы можем гарантировать, что все что определено для `Object` так же определено и для `T`

*Это основное отличие от, например, шаблонов C++, где ваш код был бы скомпилирован для удовлетворяющих этот шаблон типов.*

Для наглядности вот вам пример в котором определены операции сравнения:

```
public class Clazz
{
    private int _x;

    public Clazz(int x)
    {
        _x = x;
    }

    public static bool operator <(Clazz a, Clazz b)
    {
        return a._x < b._x;
    }

    public static bool operator >(Clazz a, Clazz b)
    {
        return a._x > b._x;
    }
}
```

Для `Object` не определены операции `>` или `<` поэтому такое определение обобщения не сработает:

```
private static bool Compare<T>(T a, T b) 
{
    return a > b;
}
```

Потому что сейчас для `T` можно подставить любой тип без ограничений. Но мы можем установить на `T` [ограничение параметров-типов](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/constraints-on-type-parameters) которые будут включать только те типы, для которых эти операции определены.

```
private static bool Compare<T>(T a, T b) where T : Clazz
{
    return a > b;
}
```

И подставлять в качестве заполнителя типа как `Clazz`, так и производные от него классы. Та же механика распространяется и на случай с интерфейсом `IComparable`. Вам нужно так же ограничить тип T на работу только с типами, которые имплементируют этот интерфейс. Cм. ответ @SmorcIRL